# Check if string contains any part of substring

Tags: java, string

I have

```
String S = "Eng - Computer, Eng - Software.."
```

User inputs:

```
String I = "Engineering."
```

I would like this to return true because S contains "Eng" part of a substring of I.

How can I do this?

```
S.trim.toLowercase.contains(....)
```

Does not properly work because of the "part" of substring.

Comment: Matcher class in Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: Unclear question.please write details about your expected output and code you tried so that I can answer

Comment: Please clarify what you consider valid substrings, e.g : is `e` a valid substring ?

Answer (score 0):

Is S a standard string that checks if a substring which enters a user is part of S?

If so, you can use the "contains" method:

```
if (I.contains("*/string that you want to check*/")
  return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

You need to tokenize `S` and then ask if `I` contains any of those tokens.

```
String S = "Eng - Computer, Eng - Software..";
String I = "Engineering.";

//neither S or I contain each other
System.out.println(S.trim().toLowerCase().contains(I));
System.out.println(I.trim().toLowerCase().contains(S));

String[] tokens = S.split(" ");

//but parts of S are contained in I...
for(String token : tokens) {
    if(I.contains(token)) {
        System.out.println("found : " +token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but it's condescending (*make sure you read it*), and gives absolutely no explanation as to why it's working, and how it's working. "Try this code"-type answers are not useful.

Comment: Fair criticism, I'll update the answer.  The embedded comments provide a *little* explanation

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean. Are you looking if any of the *words* in S are contained in I? If that's the case, I would recommend splitting S into an array of Strings for each word, and then checking if any of the words are a substring of I. Take a look at this function.

```
public boolean checkSubstring(String S, String I){
    String[] words = S.split(" ");

    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        if(I.contains(words[i])
            return true; //We found a word contained in I!
    }

    return false; //None of the words were contained in I
}
```